# Remove fitBounds from google maps and set zoom level instead

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have tried everything but can't work out how to remove the fit to bounds part of this code and set a zoom level instead. The problem is this map is designed for multiple markers but I'm currently only using it with 1 and it zooms in too close.

```
var gmarkers = [];   
var markers = [
[   '<div id="mapcontent">' +
    '<a href ="#project0"><h4>43 Short Street</h4>' +
    '</div>'    
, -27.686478,153.131745]
];

function initializeMaps() {
var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{    featureType: 'all',  stylers: [{saturation: -100},{brightness: 5} ]}  ],
    scrollwheel: false    
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions); 
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
var marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(pos);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: './img/mapmarker.png',
        position: pos,
        map: map
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }


    })(marker, i));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
initializeMaps()
           function myClick(id){
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[id], 'click');
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

to (or remove it)

```
// map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Add your desired zoom and center when you initialize the map:

```
var myOptions = {
    // change these per your desired center and zoom.
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(desiredLat, desiredLng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{    
      featureType: 'all',  
      stylers: [{
          saturation: -100
        },
        {
          brightness: 5
        }]
    }],
    scrollwheel: false    
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
```

But if you only have one marker, you should also remove the loop.

Comment: Thankyou! so obvious! More markers will be added shortly so this fix is perfect as I will just reverse the changes.